# When I run tests with scalaTestPlus and Play framework, I get an error "no started application"

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, scalatest

I'm trying to make scalaTestPlus work in my play application (I'm using Play! 2.2). It works well until I need a function coming from my application. For instance, if I run this very simple test (by launching in a sbt console "test-only TestName"):

```
import org.scalatestplus.play._
import org.scalatest._
import Matchers._

class Test extends PlaySpec {
  "This test" must {
    "run this very simple test without problem" in {
      1 mustEqual 1
    }
  }
}
```

There is no problem, but as soon as I call a function from my app, like in this code:

```
class Test extends PlaySpec {
  "This test" must {
    "run this very simple test without problem" in {
      models.Genre.genresStringToGenresSet(Option("test")) //Here is the problem 
      1 mustEqual 1
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error:  `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: at...` `Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application` (even if my application is running).

I'm probably missing something simple since I'm brand new to ScalaTest, so any help abut what I'm doing wrong would be apreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by @akauppi, here is a method that works perfectly for me:

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneAppPerSuite, PlaySpec}

class A extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  "a" must {

    "return true" in {
      //thanks to with OneAppPerSuite, it now works
      models.Genre.genresStringToGenresSet(Option("test"))
      1 mustBe 1
    }

    "return false" in {
      1 mustBe 2
    }
  }
}
```

And I simply launch the test with `sbt ~testOnly a`

Answer (score 0):

You may need an application in scope when using `PlaySpec`, as some operations assume that there is a Play application available via `Play.current`:

```
class Test extends PlaySpec {

  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication(...)

  "This test" must {
    "run this very simple test without problem" in {
      models.Genre.genresStringToGenresSet(Option("test")) //Here is the problem 
     1 mustEqual 1
  }
}
```

}

Check the [functional testing documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest) for more details on `FakeApplication`.

However, I don't think you need should need this for model testing. In the [normal ScalaTest docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest) for play, it seems to just mix in`MockitoSugar`. But your method call chain may invoke some global state of *Play* that does require an `Application`, in which case the `FakeApplication` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for your response. With the line you added, I get an error about the override and lazy, but indeed, that is the way to go. I replaced every "in" by "in new App()" and it works fine. I still wonder why I need to load an Application even if my function depend of nothing related to my application (I even tested with a function that only returns his argument.)...

Comment: Finally this solution is not working: every test I run with "in new App()" returns true even if I test if 1 mustEqual 2...

Comment: I, finally... found the solution, I just had to add with "OneAppPerTest"... (Or OneAppPerSuite.)

Comment: @user3683807 Would you like to tell a little bit more about the OneAppPerTest solution. Might be a new answer to this SO issue. I would be happy to +1 if it works for me.

Comment: Ok, I gave my answer. Ask me if you work with Play! 2.4 and you need some help to inject a class for the tests ;)